# IF comparison not working properly

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch programming and I'm currently having a problem that I don't understand... but maybe it's very easy.

So my objective is to get my PC model via the "wmic csproduct get name" command. It returns 3 lines, the second line is the one I want (the PC model), but it adds two spaces at the end of the line.

So I used this code :

```
@ECHO ON
FOR /F "usebackq delims=, skip=1" %%i IN (`wmic csproduct get name`) DO (
    SET "model=%%i"
    echo "%model%"
    goto next
    )

:next
echo The command returns %model%
IF("%model%"=="Precision WorkStation T3400  ") (echo TEST OK)
pause
goto eof
```

But when I run it, the first echo doesn't echo anything, but the second echo returns the good model AND it doens't echo TEST OK even if I manually added the two spaces... and if the IF comparison seems to be ok...

Does somebody has an idea?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There is some trick - you need to set `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` after `@ECHO ON` to re-assign %%i to model, otherwise this assignment will be evaluated once, only.

Answer (score 0):

You must start your file with `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, as already mentioned in the comments. Furthermore you must concider that `%model%` will contain the **first assigned value** and `!model!` the **current value**. So you should use **`!model!`**.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims==" %%i in (
        'wmic csproduct get name /value'
    ) do for %%a in ("%%i") do (
        SET "model=%%~a"
        echo %%~a
    )

    echo The command returns [%model%]
    IF "%model%"=="Precision WorkStation T3400" (echo TEST OK)

    pause
```

You don't need to assign the value to a variable just to echo it, so, instead of echoing the variable inside the loop, echo the `for` replaceable parameter. If for some reason you need to modify this value inside the same loop then you will need to enable delayed expansion.

`wmic` query has been changed to return the data in the format `key=value` and the `for` configured to split the lines using the `=` as a delimiter and retrieve the second token.

Also, as the output of `wmic` includes an additional carriage return at the end of the value, an additional `for` loop is included to get this character removed from the variable.

AND your `if` command has a logic problem

```
if ("a"=="a") ...
```

means *if the string `("a"` is equal to the string `"a")`* and of course they are not equal.

If it has or not aditional spaces, ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your answers.

I just added the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and it didn't work. 
Then I removed the IF brackets and it worked well!

Your code is working well as well MC ND, many thanks for your help and the explanations!